# How to get vector features by x,y,z in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, vector, features

I have a list of features in my server and I want to render them in OpenLayers.

I know I can use ol/source/Vector.js to render my features as following code:

```
const vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
  background: '#1a2b39',
  source: new VectorSource({
    url: 'https://openlayers.org/data/vector/ecoregions.json',
    format: new GeoJSON(),
  }),
  style: function (feature) {
    const color = feature.get('COLOR_NNH') || '#eeeeee';
    style.getFill().setColor(color);
    return style;
  },
});
```

But in this way, I need to return all features from the URL.

Is there any way I can just return features that are currently in sight, which means I can return features according to tile x,y,z?

Comment: If the server supports it you can request features for a bbox or extent, e.g. for WFS https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-wfs.html or ArcGIS feature server https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-esri.html  Otherwise if you no choice about loading all the data from the url you can render it as tiles using geojson-vt https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geojson-vt.html

Answer (score 0):

OpenLayers supports vector tiles, see multiple examples here:

[OpenLayers Vector Tiles examples](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/?q=Vector%20Tiles)

Please describe your source data better, as there are ways to expose data as tiles and not complete data sets. Using a bounding box in your request will get you just the relevant data, but using a tiled response is usually much faster.